# sys.syscomments.name length > 4,000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The code below displays, among other things, the source code for all the triggers in a database

```
SELECT so.name AS trigger_name,
   s.name AS table_schema,
   t.name AS table_name,
   LEN (sc.[text]) as len,
   sc.[text] AS trigger_content
FROM [GDI-193-DEV].dbo.sysobjects so
   INNER JOIN [GDI-193-DEV].sys.tables t ON so.parent_obj = t.object_id
   INNER JOIN [GDI-193-DEV].sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
   INNER JOIN [GDI-193-DEV].sys.syscomments sc ON so.id = sc.id
WHERE so.type = 'TR'
```

The problem is if the length of the trigger source code is more than 4,000 characters it ends up spanning two records in sys.syscomments.

So, for example, if the trigger source is 4,700 characters it will be spread across 2 records in sys.syscomments. sys.syscomments.TEXT in the first record will have a length of 4,000 while the remaining 700 characters will be put into another record.

This is causing problems for me as I am trying to compare the complete trigger source code between two databases.

This seem like some strange behavior. Am I missing something? Is there a different way of getting the source code that avoids this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: May be better asked on dba.

Comment: You can try using `object_definition(so.object_id)` instead of joining syscomments, I haven't tested it but it probably doesn't cap it at 4000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and found out that there's another way to get untrimmed definitions. Try if entire code of your trigger shows, and then you can work your way to joinning this to other system tables/views:

```
select top 100 
    * 
from sys.sql_modules 
where 1=1
    and definition like '%trigger%'
```

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko It's just my habit :)

Comment: Can I be sure that the definition will include the string 'trigger'? Does SQL Server put that in?

Comment: @user2135970 Check for yourself :). But yes, it contains entire definition ready to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `object_definition` like this:

```
SELECT so.name AS trigger_name,
   s.name AS table_schema,
   t.name AS table_name,
   object_definition(so.object_id) AS trigger_content
FROM [GDI-193-DEV].dbo.sysobjects so
   INNER JOIN [GDI-193-DEV].sys.tables t ON so.parent_obj = t.object_id
   INNER JOIN [GDI-193-DEV].sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE so.type = 'TR'
```